# How to get the context of the button rightclicked

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, bookmarks

I have encountered some problems in the bookmark section for my wpf web-browser. I want to be able to delete already existing buttons but I can't seem to figure out how to detect the content of the button I right click on. (To get my `ContextMenu` to show).

[My visual progress so far: http://puu.sh/6Dxat.png](http://puu.sh/6Dxat.png)

Adding a context menu to the buttons:

```
public void button_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)//add a context menu to buttons
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    menu = new ContextMenu();
    menu.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Delete" });
    button.ContextMenu = menu;
    menu.Closed += button_DeleteButtonClicked;//find the right event
 }
```

(I know that the event is wrong, but that is not important right now.)

And the event:

```
private void button_DeleteButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//delete bookmark
{
    //This is where I need help. I want the content (which is the URL) of the button 
    //right clicked onto, for example, show up in a messagebox. How to do?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have hooked *Close event of context menu* here, so sender will be `ContextMenu` here and you can get button by using [PlacementTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of ContextMenu.

```
private void button_DeleteButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = ((ContextMenu)sender).PlacementTarget as Button;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much! Did not know about the `PlacementTarget`. Thanks a lot!